# Is there a way to set a scale/minimum size to an ellipsoid the same way that minimumpixelsize (and maximumscale) does with a model?

Tags: zooming, cesiumjs, czml

I want to use a czml to draw some spheres floating around an area of the globe, and I want them to keep the same size regarless of zoom (within limits). This is trivial with a gltf model, but I cannot find a way to do it with an ellipsoid.

Comment: CZML can contain a glTF.  Any particular reason to use an ellipsoid instead?  I think the min pixel size thing is only a feature of models, not ellipsoids.

Comment: Well, I am just not familiarized with gltf and have no clue about how to create them from scratch.

Comment: Would it be enough just to get one sphere model and use it in a couple of locations?  Or does each location need a different color or something?